# Neo4j - Returning nodes in a path along with their IDs

Tags: neo4j

Assuming a query like:

MATCH path=(u:user)-[:CREATED]->(p:post)<-[:REBLOG_OF*]-(p2:post)
RETURN path

How can I get the IDs of all nodes in that path along with the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
MATCH path=(u:user)-[:CREATED]->(p:post)<-[:REBLOG_OF*]-(p2:post)
RETURN path, EXTRACT(node IN nodes(path) | ID(node))
```